# side menus interfering with a tabbed view in ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I basically have a sliding menu application. Each menu item opens up a view where I populate data. It all works great, but in one view, I want, say a ionic pager with slides. It seems the sliding menu does not let this control work. Either that or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

What happens is when I click on the "Events G" menu option it comes to the events graph html but the slides don't show up properly at all. OTOH if I remove the side menu construct, the view works great.

My menu.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-pane>


 <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Options</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>


        <!-- this view works great - its a normal view -->
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/events">
            <span class=" item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i>
            </span>
          Events
        </ion-item>

          <!-- this view messes up the display -->
          <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/events-graphs">
            <span class=" item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i>
            </span>
          Events Graph Tabs
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/filters">
            <span class=" item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-funnel"></i>
            </span>
          Filters
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/login">
            <span class=" item-icon-left">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
            </span>
            Settings
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>


</ion-side-menus>
```

Now here is the code for "events-graphs"

I'm not posting any controller code because they are currently not doing anything relevant to this example.

```
<ion-view view-title="Monitor Event Summary" cache-view="false">


<ion-content>
      <ion-slide-box>
          <ion-slide-pager> </ion-slide-pager>
              <ion-slide>
                  <!-- <canvas tc-chartjs chart-type="bar" chart-options="options" chart-data="data" auto-legend></canvas> -->
                Slide 1
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                   <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
              </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
                    Slide 3
              </ion-slide>

      </ion-slide-box>
   </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Here is what my app looks like when I move to the "Events Graph" view that should be showing a nice sliding window with 3 screens.

[image: Event Graph screen - messed up]

If I change the events-graph.html to instead display 3 tabs, I don't see tab icons and the content gets hidden under the nav bar - so I am pretty sure I am not doing something right in the side menu - but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Comment: Sharing a plnker would be better.

Comment: Here goes - see the "Help" option
http://codepen.io/asker/pen/rVBmqw

Answer (score 0):

Delete `<ion-slide-pager> </ion-slide-pager>`. It was removed in one of the beta versions. Add `show-pager="true"` to the `<ion-slide-box>` element to display the pager.